# How to cache xml document in xslt 1.0

Tags: c#-2.0, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT 1.0 and C# 2.0. and I want to cache my loaded document, so that whenever next page is called it should use cache document instead of loading it again.

Here is a part of XSLT where I am getting physical path from C# in param **sitespath**, I know I can cache this document using C#, but I am looking cache the loaded document in xslt 1.0

Sample Code:

```
<xsl:param name="sitespath"/>
<xsl:variable name="siteInfoPath" select="document($sitespath)/sitedata/region/site/language"/>
```

Now I want to cache **siteInfoPath** variable so that everytime it does not load it as document, it will first check for cached variable try to load from cache else it will load again.

Is this is possible?

Please suggest!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can cache a result of document() function in the xslt for multiple transformations. document() function is evaluated at runtime. What you can do however is to cache the document in your c# programs and pass it to the transformation as an external parameter (you would probably have to pass XPathNavigator; see XsltArgumentList.AddParam documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx for more details).

Comment: Thanks Pawel, Actually this has been already, but it will go in our next release, but I was looking some short solution so that until my next promote goes. If we can do this at xslt level then this would avoid a promote

Comment: As I said - document() method is evaluated at runtime. You can use a global variable to cache the nodes for one transformation but not for multiple (and unrelated transformation). You can think of it as of your C# program. If you set a variable to 5, end the process and run the app again the variable will not be 5 unless you set it again.